# How to replace epoch column in DataFrame with date in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am writing a spark application which receives an avro record. I am converting that avro record into Spark DataFrame (df) object.
The df contains a time stamp attribute which is in seconds. (Epoch time)

I want to replace the seconds column with the date column.
How to do that?

My code snippet is  :

```
val df = sqlContext.read.avro("/root/Work/PixelReporting/input_data/pixel.avro")
val pixelGeoOutput = df.groupBy("current_time", "pixel_id", "geo_id", "operation_type", "is_piggyback").count()
pixelGeoOutput.write.json("/tmp/pixelGeo")
```

"current_time" is in seconds right now. I want to convert it into date.

Answer (score 3):

Since Spark 1.5, there's a built in `sql.function` called `from_unixtime`, you can do:

```
val df = Seq(Tuple1(1462267668L)).toDF("epoch")
df.withColumn("date", from_unixtime(col("epoch")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys,
I used withColumn method to solve my problem.

Code snippet is :

```
val newdf = df.withColumn("date", epochToDateUDF(df("current_time")))
def epochToDateUDF = udf((current_time : Long)  =>{
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd").print(current_time *1000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea:

```
import java.util.Date
val df = sc.parallelize(List(1462267668L, 1462267672L, 1462267678L)).toDF("current_time")
val dfWithDates = df.map(row => new Date(row.getLong(0) * 1000))
dfWithDates.collect()
```

Output:

```
Array[java.util.Date] = Array(Tue May 03 11:27:48 CEST 2016, Tue May 03 11:27:52 CEST 2016, Tue May 03 11:27:58 CEST 2016)
```

You might also try this in a UDF and using `withColumn` to just replace that single column.